# Как правильно сделать отзывчивую картинку?

Tags: html, css

Есть картинка с заданными параметрами `width` и `height`. Размеры задаются для того чтобы после загрузки картинки верстка не 'прыгала'.

```
<img src="photo.jpg" width="900" height="400" class="photo">
```

Как сделать правильно responsive картинку? Проблема в том что если добавить `height: auto; max-width: 100%;` то аттрибуты `width` и `height` просто игнорируются и картинка начинает прыгать.

То есть хочется чтобы картинка была в пропорции значений `width` и `height` но при этом изменялась под размер экрана.

Возможно это можно реализовать с помощью функции css `calc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо обернуть картинку в responsive-блок, сохраняющий нужные пропорции.
Для этого воспользуемся тем фактом, что вертикальные отступы считаются от ширины.

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  padding-top: 44.444%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
before image
<figure>
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/BXz9J.jpg">
</figure>
after image
```

Comment: Почему 44.444%? (я знаю, а другие посетители не факт}

Comment: @andreymal 400 / 900 = 44.444%

Comment: Спасибо Qwertiy и @andreymal . Без уточнения про  44.444 не понял бы. Возможно это стоит пояснить в самом ответе?

Comment: @user2168735, добавил.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="img"><img src="" alt=""></div>


.img{
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 400px;
}

.img img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Привет. У меня не работает - http://output.jsbin.com/haxireximi

Comment: подправил, проверил

Comment: тут наблюдается таже проблема что и с height: auto; max-width: 100%; Пока картинка не загружена, высота блока img 18px. Можете задать background-color:red; для .img  и через инспектор удалить аттрибут src.